# Masonry layout with 3 columns but first item takes 2 columns

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve the masonry (mosaic) layout as seen on the image:

[image: layout]

Requirements: 3 columns layout, dynamic height for each item, dynamic height for the container. First item takes 2 columns. Any number of items.

Ideally I would like a pure css solution. So far I haven't managed to achieve this neither I found a solution on Internet (flexbox and column-count solutions don't allow to have single item taking multiple columns).

Comment: You can probably achieve this with CSS Grid. https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

Comment: @YoannPicquenot, I tried that, but was unable to achieve the required result. It allows for either horizontal or vertical masonry layout, but the problem is with that stand out first item which needs to take more than one column.

Comment: You can set your element to take 2 columns

Comment: @YoannPicquenot, I really tried everything that came to my mind. If you have a working solution please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as of today (2020/07/08) there is no way to achieve what I'm after with css only. It may change in the future. The only solution I've found that meets all my requirements is David DeSandro's [Masonry library](https://masonry.desandro.com/) (for React.js there is [react-masonry-component](https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component) wrapper).

If someone else wants to achieve the same here is the styles:

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 8px;
}
/* 2 columns wide */
.grid-item--width2 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
```

And inside your React component:

```js
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component';

export const MyMasonry = ({ items }) => 
  <Masonry
    className={'grid'}
    options={{
      transitionDuration: 0,
      // use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      // do not use .grid-sizer in layout
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
    }}
    >
    {/* .grid-sizer empty element, only used for element sizing */}
    <div className="grid-sizer"></div>
    {items.map((item, index) => (index === 0 ? <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2">{...content...}</div> : <div className="grid-item">{...content...}</div>))}
  </Masonry>
```

The example is taken from [here](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#element-sizing) and adapted to be used with react-masonry-component.

Answer (score 1):

That solution's not mine, I found it in the link I've shared with you in the comments above.

https://codepen.io/balazs_sziklai/pen/mOwoLg

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.grid-layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, auto);
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #929796;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    &:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #424242;
    }
}

.span-2 {
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.span-3 {
    grid-column-end: span 3;
    grid-row-end: span 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm after. I've already tried a similar solution. As you can see the height of items is not dynamic.